# Requirements to move an LXC container from host to another

Tags: openvz, lxc

What are the *requirements* and *things to know* to move an LXC container from an host to an other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, we haven't working and stable solution for this task. Bleeding of edge technology for containers live migration are OpenVZ and P.Haul (part of CRIU project): https://github.com/xemul/p.haul

As main requirement I will mention vanilla kernel from kernel.org.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Duply](http://www.duply.net/) to backup LXC containers. Unlike backing up a normal machine you **DO** want to include `/dev` from the LXC container in the backup.

Exclude the following files from the backup:

```
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/lost+found
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/media/*
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/mnt/*
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/proc/*
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/run/*
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/sys/*
- /var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/tmp/*
```

& see my notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427129/have-lxc-containers-backup) for further details.